# Spring.net / DI and loading information within an embedded resource

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, spring.net

I have a DLL that is loaded by a windows service. The service is using spring.net and the DLL contains an embedded resource xml file that defines all my objects. The DLL embedded file is using DI and I now require that we inject locally configured information at startup. My option is to move the object reference to the service app.config file but I wondered if there is a way to define a $value$ that can then be referenced inside the embedded reference ?

Comment: Found a solution. Defined a String in the app.config and referenced it in the embedded xml resource file.

Comment: can also be done using the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Answer (score 0):

http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html

Question refinement:
If you are referencing to an assembly - just put this line in app config:

```
 <spring>
  <context type="Spring.Context.Support.XmlApplicationContext, Spring.Core">
    <resource uri="assembly://MyAssembly/MyDataAccess/data-access.xml"/>
  </context>
</spring>
```

If you are loading the assembly in run-time, you're gonna have to specify it like so:

```
IApplicationContext context = new XmlApplicationContext(
             "assembly://MyAssembly/MyDataAccess/data-access.xml");
```